# Getting "The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server" even with valid connection string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to fetch all the file names from a Blob Container in Azure storage account.
This is the code I have written to do the same.

```
                string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=filesStorage;AccountKey=xxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
                string containerName = "firstContainer" + "\\" + "secondFolder";  

                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
                BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
                var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs();

                foreach (var item in blobs)
                {
                    blobFilesList.Add(item.Name);
                }
```

When I run this code , I'm getting an error at foreach statement :

> `InvalidUri`The requested URI does not
> represent any resource on the server.

But the connectionstring I'm using is correct. I'm able to login into Azure storage account using this connectionstring.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here. I searched for similar problems , but I couldn't get any relevant solution for this.  Any help is greatly helpful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're running into this issue is because you're including the name of your virtual folder when you're creating your blob container client. It should only include the blob container name.

To list the blobs from a virtual folder, you will need to pass the full path of that virtual folder as `prefix` parameter in your `GetBlobsMethod`.

Can you please try something like:

```
string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=filesStorage;AccountKey=xxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
string containerName = "firstContainer";  

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix:"secondFolder/");

foreach (var item in blobs)
{
    blobFilesList.Add(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. When I add prefix , it is giving error  : The name prefix does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! It should be `prefix:"secondFolder/"`. I have updated my answer. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobs?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_GetBlobs_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobTraits_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobStates_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_.

Comment: I have updated the code according to your answer. It is giving me result like this : secondFolder/File1.xls , secondFolder/File2.xls.  How can I get the just the file names inside virtual folder.

Comment: As you may already know, the folders (`secondFolder` in your case) in Blob Storage are virtual. The actual name of the blob is indeed `secondFolder/File1.xls`. To get just `File1.xls`, you will need to do some string manipulation yourself and remove `secondFolder/` from the name yourself. HTH.

Comment: You may want to do something like `blobFilesList.Add(item.Name.Substring(prefix.Length);` and that should give you desired result.